# Highlight text in nattable cell

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, nattable

I have a nettable with different columns and rows filled with data. I want to highlight specific text in cells when some text is searched in a text field.

After lookin into https://www.eclipse.org/nattable/nandn/nandn_150.php
I tried the following but nothing is highlighted when I press the apply button

```
this.applyButton = new Button(parent, SWT.PUSH);
this.applyButton.addSelectionListener(getSelectionListener());

private SelectionListener getSelectionListener(){
    return new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            String text = textBox.getText();
            if(!text.trim().isEmpty()) {
                applyHighlighting(text);
            }
        }
    };
}

public void applyHighlighting(String text) {
    RegexMarkupValue regexMarkup = new RegexMarkupValue("", "<span style=\"background-color:rgb(255, 255, 0)\">",
            "</span>");
    natTable.addConfiguration(new DefaultNatTableStyleConfiguration() {
        {
            this.cellPainter = new BackgroundPainter(new PaddingDecorator(new RichTextCellPainter(), 2));
        }

        @Override
        public void configureRegistry(IConfigRegistry configRegistry) {
            super.configureRegistry(configRegistry);
            // markup for highlighting
            MarkupDisplayConverter markupConverter = new MarkupDisplayConverter();
            markupConverter.registerMarkup("highlight", regexMarkup);
            // register markup display converter for normal display mode in the body
            configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(CellConfigAttributes.DISPLAY_CONVERTER, markupConverter,
                    DisplayMode.NORMAL, GridRegion.BODY);
        }
    });
    regexMarkup.setRegexValue(text.isEmpty() ? "" : "(" + text + ")");
}
```

so with this I assumed when I type something in the text field and click on apply button text in the cells provided in the text field should be highlighted but nothing is changed. Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to highlight parts of a text inside a cell, you need the Nebula Extension. It is described in the New & Noteworthy of 1.5

https://www.eclipse.org/nattable/nandn/nandn_150.php

There is also a pointer to the corresponding example.

Comment: Is it possible to highlight the text in cell without using the extension?

Comment: Only if you implement a painter that is possible to render text this way. NatTable provides this feature only via the RichTextCellPainter

Comment: Can you please have a look into the edited code and help me with what I am doing wrong

Comment: Code seems correct. Do you have a grid composition with a grid region that has the region label BODY?

Comment: yes I have viewportLayer.setRegionName(GridRegion.BODY);

Comment: I have updated the code for better understanding of what I am doing

Comment: I took your code and put it in one of the NatTable examples (despite the layouting). It works as intended. If you do not see any data, maybe your data provider is empty.

Comment: Can you paste that example here so I can try it with my local env Please?

Comment: It is the same code as yours, I just don't have the SWT layout stuff and I use the data provider from the examples, as you haven't posted it. Your code can not be tested as most of the code needed for the execution is missing. I have not changed anything else.

Comment: Do I need this package for highlighting becuse I removed it from the extension source code org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.extension.nebula\src\org\eclipse\nebula\widgets\nattable\extension\nebula\cdatetime

Comment: No, but why do you modify the sources?

Comment: Just wanted to quickly try the highlighting except everything else, not indented to change the sources

Comment: But why do you then change the sources or build from sources instead of consuming the bundles from a p2 update site or Maven Central?

Comment: Didn't know that its available via p2 update site will use that

Comment: So the only suspicious thing I need to test is that make sure that my dataprovider is not empty?

Comment: If you don't see data in the table shown above, either your data provider is empty, the layouting is somehow incorrect and does not layout correctly, or you somehow override the configuration outside, as you seem to expose the ConfigRegistry via a field. The rest of the code you show seems to be correct (which I expected as it is almost equal to the code I have published as example)

Comment: now I see the data but the cell which contains main is not highlighted but the data in that cell is shown as <span style="background-color:rgb(255, 255, 0)">main</span>

Comment: Then the wrong cell painter is used. Probably the RichTextCellPainter you registered is overriden somewhere.

Comment: Do I need TextMatcherEditor for highlighting the text in table content?

Comment: No that is for filtering

Comment: Thanks, I have also updated my code if you can have a look

Comment: You forgot to refresh the table. It needs to be repainted to make the changes visible. `natTable.refresh(false);` have a look at the example to get the whole picture as I said right at the beginning https://github.com/eclipse/nebula.widgets.nattable/blob/master/org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.examples/src/org/eclipse/nebula/widgets/nattable/examples/_600_GlazedLists/_603_Filter/_6036_SingleFieldFilterExample.java

Comment: Thank you for your help the highlighting works now, one question is there a way to navigate between the highlighted text in the table?

Comment: I have text highlighting added in my nattable, if text in a cell is not visible and it matches the text being searched the cell is highlighted in the bottom, is it the expected behavior? and can we somehow avoid that? I added a screenshot of cell bottom highlighting

Comment: Well I suppose this is caused by the row height. There is a second row that is not completely visible, but the row height is big enough to show at least the top pixels of the next row. Maybe reducing the row height helps here, or you configure the TextPainter with some spacing between the rows.

Comment: I am using rich text cell painter for highlighting but it does not highlight < and > signs though I escape them.

Comment: Is there a question? I mean do you expect those characters are handled by a painter that parses html?

Comment: you mean a separate question for this? I have a NatTable and a search bar on top of it, the content of the table contains < and > signs. When I type < and > in the searchbar it is not highlighted though it is in the table... Does the rich text painter does not have the capability to highlight < and > signs?

Comment: "do you expect those characters are handled by a painter that parses html?" yes can they be handled so they get highlighted?

Comment: It's html that gets parsed and painted. I would assume that such characters are treated as tag characters. Never tried that

Comment: yeah seems like treated as html tags... any suggestions ?